# Javascript - Focus element on keydown, when no element in the page has focus

Tags: javascript, focus, onkeydown

I have a set of buttons. When they have focus, they change color.
They can get focus when the user hovers over them or when the user uses the up and down arrow keys.

When no button has focus (when the user clicks somewhere else, for example), pressing the arrow keys will shift the focus to the first button. At least, that's what is intended.

However, since I have the same keys performing different things, whenever I press the down key the focus goes to the first button, and immediately to the second one.

I cannot seem to find a way to make this work as I would like it to. Is there anything I can do at all to keep the focus on the first button when the down arrow key is pressed, when no button has focus?

This is what I am working with:

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("blueBtn");
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 38) {
            if (this.previousElementSibling) {
                this.previousElementSibling.focus();
            }
        } else if (event.keyCode == 40) {
            if (this.nextElementSibling) {
                this.nextElementSibling.focus();
            }
        }
    }, false);
    divs[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
        this.focus();
    }, false);
}

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if (document.body === document.activeElement && (event.keyCode === 38 || event.keyCode === 40)) {
        defaultBtn.focus();
    }
});
```

```css
.blueBtn {
    display: block;
}

.blueBtn:hover,
.blueBtn:focus {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<button id="defaultBtn" class="blueBtn" autofocus>Button 01</button>
<button class="blueBtn">Button 02</button>
<button class="blueBtn">Button 03</button>
<button class="blueBtn">Button 04</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must other, even better ways to do this, but here is my suggestion. I just used a boolean variable to keep track of when the focus is coming from the body.

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("blueBtn");
var fromBody = false;

for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  divs[i].addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 38) {
      if (fromBody) {
        fromBody = false;
        return;
      }
      if (this.previousElementSibling) {
        this.previousElementSibling.focus();
      }
    } else if (event.keyCode == 40) {
      if (fromBody) {
        fromBody = false;
        return;
      }
      if (this.nextElementSibling && !fromBody) {
        this.nextElementSibling.focus();
      }
    }
  }, false);
  divs[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
    this.focus();
  }, false);
}

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (document.body === document.activeElement && (event.keyCode === 38 || event.keyCode === 40)) {
    fromBody = true;
    defaultBtn.focus();
  }
});
```

```css
.blueBtn {
  display: block;
}

.blueBtn:hover,
.blueBtn:focus {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<button id="defaultBtn" class="blueBtn" autofocus>Button 01</button>
<button class="blueBtn">Button 02</button>
<button class="blueBtn">Button 03</button>
<button class="blueBtn">Button 04</button>
```

Comment: It is an interesting approach, however, if the focus is on the body and I press the up arrow key to focus the first button, then I will need to press the down arrow key twice to move to the next button. Is there a way to correct this?

Comment: I've made a couple of edits to the code so that you only have to press the down arrow key once to move to the next button in the above scenario.

I just added the if statement to the logic for the up arrow key